# Accessing Microsoft Graph API (for OneDrive) from ASP.Net Web API & MVC Web Application.

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a .Net Core Application using IdentityServer4 with Custom UserStore implemented for Authentication. 
Now I want to access Graph API for currently logged in User 
(user from Custom UserStore and having same username/email on Azure AD).

The requirement is to redirect a user to Graph Consent Screen when a user tries to access a resource on OneDrive if not already authenticated.

I created an app Azure Application Registration Portal but confused with examples provided as they use OAuth for authentication and I am already using IdentityServer4.

I'm following this;
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to access Microsoft Graph, but you have your own Identity Server.

The example from official document only shows how to get accesstoken.

In this case, you have your own Identity Server, which means you can use [Get Access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

As the official document mentioned, you can run it as a background services or daemons.

We can get accesstoken from this background services when we need it and use it to call Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Yes. I have my own IdentityServer (IdentityServer4)  but I want to access Graph API on Behalf of user. 
The difference in my case is,  user logs in to the application using their accounts created on Custom User store of Identityserver. 
The Email address on Azure and on Custom store will be same that i want to use to get access to Graph API on behalf of a logged in user.

Comment: According to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview),  your app must acquire an access token from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), Microsoft's cloud identity service to call MS Graph

Comment: Yes. I guess i have to use Authorization_Code flow but not sure how?
i have to pass use email, scope required and other info to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize  and i will get a Code which further need to send to get access_token.

Comment: You can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) to get an accesstoken

Comment: can you please refer some code sample using instructions mentioned in this document?

Comment: we can refer  [the official simple code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2)